# SqlDataReader with two tables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I have a very simple code which fetches data from two tables

1. Inventory
2. Category

and displays them in two different `GridView` controls using `SqlDataReader` in the `Page_Load` event of an ASP.NET web application.

My point is, shouldn't `SqlDataReader` automatically traverse to the next table (`Category`) after reading the data from the previous table (`Inventory`)?  Instead of using `NextResult()`, if I had **reused** the `rdr` object again for the next grid i.e. `CategoryGridView` without executing `NextResult()`, I'd get nothing (meaning it has moved on from `Inventory`?!)

So in a nutshell my question is where is the `rdr` pointing towards *after* reading from the first table (`Inventory`)?

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblInventory; Select * from tblCategory", con);
    con.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        InventoryGridView.DataSource = rdr;
        InventoryGridView.DataBind();

        rdr.NextResult();
        CategoryGridView.DataSource = rdr;
        CategoryGridView.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: After completely reading the first result set, the reader points to "nowhere" - to past the end of the first result set. But it will **not** automatically jump to the second result set - you **must use** `.NextResult()` to achieve this

Comment: Interesting, actually the confusion came from using `SQLDataReader` to read multiple rows which requires `Read()` before retrieving values.

Answer (score 2):

```
connection.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblInventory; Select * from tblCategory", connection);
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    InventoryGridView.DataSource = reader;
    InventoryGridView.DataBind();

    while (reader.NextResult())
    {
        CategoryGridView.DataSource = reader;
        CategoryGridView.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: The best practice is to add a `reader.Read()` inside the `reader.NextResult()` so you can avoid calling blank results. In fact, if (reader.NextResult()){ while (reader.Read()) } works better.